# Mysqli insert id returning null

Tags: php, mysql-insert-id

```
$S = "INSERT INTO ". TBD ." (NODE, AV, BV) VALUES ('15', '$name', '$email')";
$Q = $CONN->query($S);
$M = $Q->insert_id;
```

---

`$M` returns `NULL` not `0`

---

The above script runs the query fine, but will not return the unique ID generated.
The table, definitely has a auto increment and is a primary key.
I have used the script elsewhere and works fine.

So I have no idea why its returning NULL now.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark the helping answer with the green check on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are calling `insert_id` wrong. Try this:

```
$S = "INSERT INTO ". TBD ." (NODE, AV, BV) VALUES ('15', '$name', '$email')";
$Q = $CONN->query($S);
$M = $CONN->insert_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I got my self in such a fuss I couldn't see the obvious. Once again many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the `insert_id` from the **connection object** and not the result set.

Your `$Q` variable is a [mysqli result object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues) so you'll want to extract the inserted id like this:

```
$CONN->insert_id;
```